# Coq "convoy pattern"

Tags: coq, dependent-type, convoy-pattern

I am trying to use "convoy pattern" to preserve dependency between 3 variables (two parameters and return value):

```
Require Import Vector.

(* "sparse" vector type *)
Notation svector A n := (Vector.t (option A) n).

Fixpoint svector_is_dense {A} {n} (v:svector A n) : Prop :=
  match v with
  | Vector.nil => True
  | Vector.cons (None) _ _ => False
  | Vector.cons (Some _) _ xs => svector_is_dense xs
  end.

Lemma svector_tl_dense {A} {n} {v: svector A (S n)}:
  svector_is_dense v -> svector_is_dense (Vector.tl v).
Admitted.

Lemma svector_hd {A} {n} (v:svector A (S n)): svector_is_dense v -> A.
Admitted.

Fixpoint vector_from_svector {A} {n} {v:svector A n} (D:svector_is_dense v): Vector.t A n :=
  match n return (svector A n) -> (svector_is_dense v) -> (Vector.t A n) with
  | O => fun _ _ => @Vector.nil A
  | (S p) => fun v0 D0 => Vector.cons
                            (svector_hd v0 D0)
                            (vector_from_svector (Vector.tl v) (svector_tl_dense D))
  end v D.
```

The problem arises in last definition. Any suggestions why it is not working?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You got it almost right. The issue is in your `return` clause, which is non-dependent. What you need is

```
match n return forall (w: svector A n), (svector_is_dense w) -> (Vector.t A n) with
```

so that `D0` is not of type `svector_is_dense v` as it would be in your case, but `svector_is_dense v0`.

By the way, in the second constructor, I guess you meant `Vector.tl v0` and `svector_tl_dense D0`. Here is the full term I wrote (don't mind the additionnal `_` in `cons`, I don't have implicits activated):

```
Fixpoint vector_from_svector {A} {n} {v:svector A n} (D:svector_is_dense v): Vector.t A n :=
  match n return forall (w:svector A n), (svector_is_dense w) -> (Vector.t A n) with
  | O => fun _ _ => @Vector.nil A
  | (S p) => fun v0 D0 => Vector.cons _
                            (svector_hd v0 D0) _
                            (vector_from_svector (svector_tl_dense D0))
  end v D.
```